# Regular Expression to pull out part of a string

Tags: regex

I need some help trying to select a certain part of a string with regular expression.

Here is the string.

```
http://site.com/bathroom.jpg&h=165&w=204&zc=1&q=90&a=c
```

And I need to select "&h=165&w=204&zc=1&q=90&a=c" part of it out.

Would regular expression be the best approach to this and if so, how?

Thanks...

Comment: Shouldn't that actually be a `?` to start the query string, not a `&`? Also, what language are you using?

Comment: Yeah, what language are you using? And, is this the URL of the page the person is actually on, or is this a URL that's stored somewhere that you need to parse? Because if it's the URL of the page, you will be able to prob use $_SERVER variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the first `&` and take everything starting from it. The regex:

```
&.*
```

Comment: Thank you...I had & and didn't think to put .*

Answer (score 0):

use substring like

```
function getSecondPart(str) {
    return str.split('jpg')[1];
}
// use the function:
alert(getSecondPart("http://site.com/bathroom.jpg&h=165&w=204&zc=1&q=90&a=c"));
```